# Custom Serialization of data array

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a problem:

```
    protected Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {         
        sx = info.GetUInt16("sizex");
        sy = info.GetUInt16("sizey");
        sz = info.GetUInt16("sizez");
        ushort[] tab = new ushort[sx * sy * sz];
        tab = info.GetValue("data", System.UInt16[sx * sy * sz]);
        Console.WriteLine("Deserializing constructor");
    }
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Serializing...");
        info.AddValue("sizex", sx);
        info.AddValue("sizey", sy);
        info.AddValue("sizez", sz);           
        info.AddValue("data", tab);
    }
```

I get a compile-time error: 'ushort' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context. 
What should I change  ?

Comment: how you are using sx,sy,sz in "GetObjectData" and they are local to the function "Test"?

Answer (score 3):

info.GetValue expects a type, so you do not include a size for the array and you wrap it with a typeof. Also, `ushort[] tab = new ushort[sx * sy * sz];` is unnecessary.

```
ushort[] tab = (ushort[])info.GetValue("data", typeof(ushort[]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    protected Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {         
        sx = info.GetUInt16("sizex");
        sy = info.GetUInt16("sizey");
        sz = info.GetUInt16("sizez");
        ushort[] tab = new ushort[sx * sy * sz];
        tab = (ushort[])info.GetValue("data", tab.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Deserializing constructor");
    }
```